# lumen.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Fatal error: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\dispatch()

Tags: php, laravel, email, lumen, bulk-email

I am working on Lumen for sending bulk mailing but I am getting an error like,

Stack trace:

> [2018-07-27 04:57:14] lumen.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Fatal error:
>   Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\dispatch() in
>   /chroot/home/milopleo/milople.org/html/development/harsh/presvi/api/app/Http/Controllers/EmailController.php:15

And these are the steps which I followed,
https://appdividend.com/2017/12/21/laravel-queues-tutorial-example-scratch/

Comment: It's hard to guess without rest of the code but the error message says that you're missing `dispatch()` function. Try adding "\" in front of the function name and check [Lumen queue documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/queues) especially differences between Laravel and Lumen

Answer (score 1):

you are using `Lumen` which does not have helper methods so you should

```
new PendingDispatch($job); //replace this with dispatch
```

Hope this helps.